# CSV file parsing issue: Different time format from Excel (using Java)

Tags: java, excel, csv

I'm trying to read and parse time from a csv file (excel), but there are different formats of time due to Excel's feature of removing leading zero. Like this:

```
1/1/2021,9:05:28
1/1/2021,2:48:32
1/1/2021,15:11:00
2/1/2021,14:37:38
```

Time like **09:05:28** became **9:05:28** in Excel, that it can't be parsed together with 14:37:38 format.

```
ArrayList<className> list = new ArrayList<>();

List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("file.csv"));
for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
    String[] elements = lines.get(i).split(",");
    // Read data from file
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(elements[0]);
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(elements[1]);
    list.add(new className(date, time));
}
```

How can I detect and read different formats of time? I need it as **Time**, not String. Or perhaps is there any method to keep leading zeros in Excel? I failed to do so as Excel doesn't save data format.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple formats on you DateTimeFormatterBuilder object like given below.

```java
private static void dateSample() throws IOException {
        ArrayList<TimeDataCsv> list = new ArrayList<>();
        DateTimeFormatter dateOnlyFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/yyyy"))
                .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/MM/yyyy"))
                .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/M/yyyy"))
                .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"))
                .toFormatter();

        DateTimeFormatter timeOnlyFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm:ss"))
                .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"))
                .toFormatter();
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("sample.csv"));
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
            String[] elements = lines.get(i).split(",");
            String dateString = elements[0].trim();
            String timeString = elements[1].trim();
            LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, dateOnlyFormatter);
            LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(timeString, timeOnlyFormatter);
            list.add(new TimeDataCsv(LocalDateTime.of(date, time)));
        }        
    }

    public static class TimeDataCsv {
        public LocalDate date;
        public LocalTime time;
        public LocalDateTime dateTime;

        public TimeDataCsv(LocalDate date, LocalTime time) {
            this.date = date;
            this.time = time;
        }

        public TimeDataCsv(LocalDateTime dateTime) {
            this.dateTime = dateTime;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a lenient DateTimeFormatter your dates work, i.e.:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .parseLenient()
    .appendPattern("dd/MM/yyyy").appendLiteral(",").appendPattern("HH:mm:ss")
    .toFormatter();
```